# PHP Error Undefinex Index

Tags: php, api

Estoy trabajando con una api y al intentar acceder a los datos que me devuelve la api, me encuentro con el error "Undefined Index".

Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
$trabajos = json_decode(file_get_contents('url'));
$data = $trabajos->data;
```

Si muestro la variable $data con un var_dump o un print_r me muestra todos los valores que contiene el archivo json sin problemas:

```
current_page": 1,
"data": [
{
  "id": 3640363,
  "deleted_at": null,
  "created_at": "2023-01-04T21:23:09.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2023-01-04T22:24:24.000000Z",
  "user_id": 25127,
  "game_id": 1,
  "company_id": 291 ....
```

Pero al intentar acceder a un valor en concrecto me devuelve el error "Undefined Index"

```
echo $data['id'];
```

Alguién sabe el porque del error ??

Muchas gracias.

Comment: $data['data']['id']; ?????

Comment: Te está devolviendo un json que es un array que contiene objetos. Para acceder a una propiedad de uno de los objetos (no se ve si vienen más) debes acceder primero al índice. Para ello, sería `$data[0]["id"]` ese 0 sería el índice. Si vienen más, puedes recorrer ese índice para ir cogiendo cada uno de los id (por ejemplo)

Comment: No responderé a miedo a equivocarme, pero hasta ahora todo json lo he usado como $data->id ... ahora no se si es asi lo tuyo

Comment: No me digáis como, pero ya me funciona, no he tocado nada .. quizás había un problema con la API y por eso no me funcionaba bien.